# Remove an element with single Linked List (Explanation needed)

Tags: java

I gone through one site. it has given following code set.
it works perfectly and I completed my task. But I have a doubt with this code. And I am unable to find.

Code:

```
public  class Node 
{ 
    private int data; 
    private Node next; 
    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }


    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    /**
     * @return the next
     */
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }


    /**
     * @param next the next to set
     */
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }


    Node(int d) 
    { 
        data = d; 
        next = null; 
    } 
}

class Sam 
{ 
    Node head;  // head of list 

    /* Linked list Node*/

    /* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
    public void push(int new_data) 
    { 
        /* 1 & 2: Allocate the Node & 
                  Put in the data*/
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data); 

        /* 3. Make next of new Node as head */
        new_node.setNext(head); 

        /* 4. Move the head to point to new Node */
        head = new_node; 
    } 

    /* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list 
       and a position, deletes the node at the given position */
    void deleteNode(int position) 
    { 
        // If linked list is empty 
        if (head == null) 
            return; 

        // Store head node 
        Node temp = head; 

        // If head needs to be removed 
        if (position == 0) 
        { 
            head = temp.getNext();   // Change head 
            return; 
        } 

        // Find previous node of the node to be deleted 
        for (int i=0; temp!=null && i<position-1; i++) 
            temp = temp.getNext(); 

        // If position is more than number of ndoes 
        if (temp == null || temp.getNext() == null) 
            return; 

        // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted 
        // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted 
        Node next = temp.getNext().getNext(); 

        temp.setNext(next);  // Unlink the deleted node from list 
    } 

    /* This function prints contents of linked list starting from 
        the given node */
    public void printList() 
    { 
        Node tnode = head; 
        while (tnode != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(tnode.getData()+" "); 
            tnode = tnode.getNext(); 
        } 
    } 

    /* Drier program to test above functions. Ideally this function 
       should be in a separate user class.  It is kept here to keep 
       code compact */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        /* Start with the empty list */
        Sam llist = new Sam(); 

        llist.push(7); 
        llist.push(1); 
        llist.push(3); 
        llist.push(2); 
        llist.push(8);
        llist.push(23);
        llist.push(56);

        System.out.println("\nCreated Linked list is: "); 
        llist.printList(); 

        llist.deleteNode(4);  // Delete node at position 4 

        System.out.println("\nLinked List after Deletion at position 4: "); 
        llist.printList(); 
    } 
}
```

Here is my doubt.

In 'deleteNode(int position)' method 'header' is assigned to new object('temp')
And below changes done with temp, I am ok with that. after this temp object copy didn't assign to header.

Node next = temp.getNext().getNext();

```
    temp.setNext(next);
```

But in printList method they used header object, and it display remaining elements after removal

```
 public void printList() 
    { 
        Node tnode = head; 
        while (tnode != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(tnode.getData()+" "); 
            tnode = tnode.getNext(); 
        } 
    }
```

I just wondering how could be the changes of temp object replaced with header object (without assign temp object to header object)

Please any one help me on this

Comment: Could you clarify your question, in your sample code you create a the list `56 23 8 2 3 1 7`, if you `deleteNode` at position 4 it'll remove "3" and return a list `56 23 8 2 1 7`... which seems right to me.

Comment: @Ambro-r I mentioned clearly that code works well and good. I just need a explanation on remove method. please read the description clearly

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a LinkedList 1,2,3,4,5

Inside *void deleteNode(int position)* method, both head and temp are pointing to the node 1. If we want to delete a node at position 2 (node with value 3) in the list, its iterating temp until position-1 which is node with value 2.

When temp is at node with value 2 then next node is 3 & its next node is 4 is assigned to next of node 2 effectively deleting 3 as 2 is pointing to 4 directly. Note its still temp node which is being altered.

head is still pointing to 1 and so printing is working fine.

If you observe carefully head is unchanged in the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine
The purpose of **Header** in Delete Function is to keep pointing to First Node of Linked List.
The purpose of **temp** in Delete Function is to travel to that node which is at position-1 location and change next linking address.
**Your Question:**
How the changes will be saved, if not assigning back to header?

Answer:A person of basic programming language knowledge will understand that any change to a variable occurs immediately.In case of Linked List , all Nodes are Linked to one another.If temp is assigned to header, the head of the linked list will become unreachable.Which we don't want as header is only variable pointing to head of linked list in whole program.
Temp means temporary variable which is discarded after use.

Comment: Yes, I got the point. I understood wrongly. I thought new copy of all nodes will be created when we assign header to temp.